# Как правильно создать раздел "Правила" в Android игре-головоломке и нужно ли?

Tags: android, unity3d, разработка-игр, google-play-games

Добрый день. Разрабатываю свою первую игру и столкнулся с таким вопросом: А как правильно создать раздел с правилами игры или же это просто экран с текстом? Нужно ли вообще делать кнопку с правилами для игры головоломки? Есть ли какие-то стандарты насчет описания правил игры или можно вкратце описать как правильно играть?

Игроделы, направьте меня в нужное русло. Расскажите как правильно, если дадите какие-либо ссылки по данной теме буду признателен.

Comment: Изучите конкурентов (другие игры)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нету каких то норм и правил в описании правил игрового процесса, хорошим тоном является создание пошагового туториала, шаг за шагом, в процессе игры, ты подкидываешь игроку небольшие кусочки правил, по принципу от простого к сложному. Если же правила игры не очень сложны то можешь их вынести либо в отдельный пункт меню, при этом не забыв при первом запуске игры предложить игроку ознакомиться с ними, либо же просто сделав кнопочку "?" на игровом поле которая будет открывать всплывающее окно с текстом правил.

Что бы проверить насколько хорошо и понятно у тебя все сделано можешь использовать банально "коридорное тестирование", это значит берешь несколько случайных знакомых, даешь им поиграть и смотришь где у них возникают непонятки что и как делать, собрав от них информацию исправляешь и тестируешь уже на других и тд.

Comment: Спасибо, мне все ясно. Думал, что есть какие-либо определенные стандарты как это есть с субтитрами к играм.